# Failed loading app.styl when using Aurelia CLI with webpack, stylus and pug

Tags: webpack, aurelia, pug-loader

I can't entirely get the configuration right to make pug work with Aurelia CLI (0.33.1) and am hoping someone knows enough about webpack loaders to help me out. I get the error `Failed loading required CSS file: app.styl`.

I've created two minimalist projects using the cli and stylus:

1. the cli and standard options (including using stylus)
2. same as #1, except modified to support pug

   - [modification instructions here](http://jimpravetz.com/blog/2018/05/webpack-pug-aurelia/)
   - [link to this sample Aurelia project here](https://github.com/jpravetz/aurelia-webpack-pug-stylus)

With #1, if I create `app.styl` and reference it using a `<require from="app.styl"></require>` from within `app.html` it loads fine. But with #2 it does not. Any ideas?

Beyond this first issue, my next unresolved issue will be to figure out how to pass locals to `index.pug`, given that `pug-loader` returns a function and needs `apply-loader` in the loader chain.

Repeating code from the [sample project](https://github.com/jpravetz/aurelia-webpack-pug-stylus):

`rules:
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loaders: [
          { loader: 'apply-loader' }, 
          { loader: 'pug-loader', options: { pretty: true } }
        ]
      },`

`plugins:
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.pug',
      inject: true,   // not sure if this is needed, or why
      metadata: {
        // wish to make this available in index.pug, but failing
        title, server, baseUrl
      }
    }),
    new AureliaPlugin( { viewsExtensions: '.pug' } ),`